# what is the difference between ngClass and [ngClass] in angular6

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

can some one please specify the difference between ngclass = "" and [ngClass] = "{'class name'}".

Comment: [ngClass] is a form of attribute binding in Angular. Anything in `[ ]` is an attribute with a one way binding from component to template, anything within `( )` is a one way event binding from template to component, and anything within `[( )]` is a two way data bound attribute

Answer (score 1):

`ngClass` gets value as string only ,but if you use `[ngClass]` it will try to get value as any variable. Also you can set and object to set classes under conditions. Like: `{active:valueOne===valueTwo}`.

```
<some-element [ngClass]="'first second'">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="['first', 'second']">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="stringExp|arrayExp|objExp">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="{'class1 class2 class3' : true}">...</some-element>
```

More details here: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass